# ContentPresenter instead of UserControl is added to my custom panel

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, itemscontrol

I have created a custom panel inherited from Canvas. I would like to use it to view my user controls in ItemsControl.

This is my XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <c:MyCustomPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemContainerTemplate>
                <app:MyUserControl Margin="5" MinWidth="200"/>                    
            </ItemContainerTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

As you can see, my user control has MinWidth set to 200.

Now, in my custom panel there is ArrangeOverride method overriden:

```
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement obj in InternalChildren)
        {
           //some other code   
        }
        return arrangeSize;
    }
```

The problem is that for some reason InternalChildren consist of ContentPresenter items instead of my user controls. In every ContentPresenter there is my user control of course, but this is not what I would like to be. I need to read here the MinWidth of my userControl, but instead I read it from ContentPresenter (which is always 0).

When I do very simple test:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <c:MyCustomPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

where Buttons is just list of Button controls, everything works as expected. So I think that the problem may be somewhere in how I use ItemsControl. But don't have any idea how to repair it.

Comment: The `ItemsControl` wraps all items in a `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: So why in example with buttons I get buttons instead of CP?

Comment: Because there is no `ContentPresenter` created nor any `ItemTemplate` applied for `UIElements` like `Buttons`.

Comment: To be precise, only those items that are not UIElements are wrapped in a ContentPresenter. So if you assign a collection of Buttons to the ItemsSource property, they are not wrapped, but instead directly added to the ItemsPanel.

Comment: The only way to get `MyUserControl` added as direct child of `MyCustomPanel` is to create a derived ItemsControl and override the `GetContainerForItemOverride` and `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` methods.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the MinWidth property of the ContentPresenter in an ItemContainerStyle:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <c:MyCustomPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <app:MyUserControl Margin="5"/>                    
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="200"/>                    
        </Style >
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that for some reason InternalChildren consist of ContentPresenter items instead of my user controls.

This is because the `ItemsControl` wraps all items in a `ContentPresenter` unless they are `UIElements`. If you bind to a collection of `UIElements`, like for example `Buttons`, there is no `ContentPresenter` created but there is also no `ItemTemplate` applied.

You could either set the `MinWidth` of the `ContentPresenter` containers as suggested by @Clemens, or you could prevent the `ContentPresenters` from getting created by implementing your own custom `ItemsControl` and override the `GetContainerForItemOverride()` and `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride()` methods:

```
public class MyItemsControl : System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl
{
    protected virtual DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new MyUserControl();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return (item is MyUserControl);
    }
}
```